# how do I read a the values of an array that is nested inside of an associative array

Tags: javascript, arrays, jsx

Here is my dilemma, I am writing a lorem ipsum generator (mostly as a fun pet project). I created a asscociative array containing the ipsum text phrases in an array.

My array structure is as follows

```
const ipsums = [
  { id: 1,
    name: 'ipsumName',
    sentences: 
      [
      'sentance',
      'sentance',
      'sentence',
      ...
      ...
      ...
      ]
   },
  { id: 2,
    name: 'ipsumName',
    sentences: 
      [
      'sentance',
      'sentance',
      'sentence',
      ...
      ...
      ...
      ]
   },
   ...
   ...
   ...
```

I am trying to access the individual sentences but when I use console.log see it, I get 'undefined.

this is my code where I'm trying to display the sentances. I've tried a few ways but I get 'undefined' in my console window.

```
const currentIpsum = ipsums.filter(ipsum => ipsum.id == activeIpsum)    
console.log(currentIpsum);
```

This does display the filtered ipsum but if I try and console log the sentences by doing the following I get 'undefined'. BTW, the activeIpsum is a value coming in from a form select field which corresponds to the id of the ipsum in the associative array.

```
console.log(currentIpsum.sentences);
```

additionally, if I try and add an index to get a specific sentence I get undefined as well.

```
console.log(currentIpsum[sentences[3]);
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here, Thank you in advanced..

Comment: `currentIpsum` is an array because `filter` returns an array: it does not have a `sentences` property. The object(s) inside the array have that. You can do `currentIpsum[0].sentences` or something similar. However if instead of `filter` you use `find`, then you will have one object (or undefined), and your code will work.

Comment: In Javascript there are no such things as associative arrays, it would be clearer in your mind to call them "objects" (with named properties). I won't go into details but if later you dig into the prototype nature of Js, you'll see. For your problem as trincot pointed, `filter` returns a filtered array, so you have to access an index (`0` here if your filter is guaranteed to leave at least one element)

Comment: Ok thanks. Yes, adding [0] worked perfectly, I can look at doing find instead but there will always be result when filtered. Also thanks, for pointing out the clarification and calling these associative arrays rather then objects. I will remember that in the future.

Comment: One detail that can help: it's an important distinction because in Js arrays are actually objects and you can add properties to them (they have already one by default: `length`). We often see beginners adding named properties to array and wonder why you cannot loop on them like we do normally (it's not an index, but a named property)